# Use PHPmailer to send attachment

Tags: php, phpmailer, email-attachments

I'm using PHPmailer library to send emails and I need to send an attachment.

Currently the file is stored on the server and I have the link to the file stored in var `$link`.

I'm using the following to try and add the attachment but the email arrives with no attachment:

```
$phpmailer->AddAttachment('$link');
```

I have also tried it with a hardcoded path instead of my variable:

```
$phpmailer->AddAttachment('http://mysite.co.uk/link/to/my/file.pdf');
```

The email shows up but does not have any attachment.

I have tried using `phpmailerException` to grab any errors but get no response.

How else can I send an attachment with PHPmailer?

Full PHP code:

```
require_once 'library/PHPMailer.php';
        $phpmailer = new PHPMailer();
        $phpmailer->isSMTP(); //switch to smtp
        $phpmailer->Host = 'smtp.sendgrid.net';
        $phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true;
        $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
        $phpmailer->Port = 465;
        $phpmailer->Username = 'username';
        $phpmailer->Password = 'password';
        $phpmailer->AddAttachment('http://mysite.co.uk/blah/cv.pdf');
        //$phpmailer->AddAttachment('$link');

        $subject = 'Job Application';

        $messageConfirmation = "The <b> 'Apply for Job' </b> form has recently been completed on <b>www.mysite.com.</b><br/><br/> <b>Please see contact details below:<br /><br/> </b>";
        $messageConfirmation.= "<b>Applying for:</b> $title <br/><br/>";
        $messageConfirmation .= "<b>Name:</b> $name <br/><br/><b>Surname:</b> $surname <br/><br/> <b>Email:</b> $email <br/><br/> <b>Comment:</b> $comment <br/><br/>";
        $messageConfirmation .= "<b>CV:</b> $link<br /><br />";
        $messageConfirmation .= "Please can you call them back in the next 24 hours. <br/><br/> Thank you \n\nMy Site<br/><br/>";


        $imgheader = 'http://blah.co.uk/blah/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/header.png';
        $imgfooter = 'http://blah.co.uk/blah/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/footer.png';

        $message = '<!DOCTYPE HTML>'.
            '<head>'.
            '<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html">'.
            '<title>Email notification</title>'.
            '</head>'.
            '<body>'.
            '<div id="header" style="width: 600px;height: auto;margin: 0 auto;color: #fff;text-align: center;font-family: Open Sans,Arial,sans-serif;">'.
            '<img src="'.$imgheader.'" >'.
            '</div>'.

            '<div id="outer" style="width: 600px;margin: 0 auto;margin-top: 10px;">'.
            '<div id="inner" style="width: 600px;margin: 0 auto; padding-left: 20px;background-color: #fff;font-family: Open Sans,Arial,sans-serif;font-size: 13px;font-weight: normal;color: #444;margin-top: 10px;">'.
            '<p>'.$messageConfirmation .'</p>'.

            '</div>'.
            '</div>'.

            '<div id="footer" style="width: 600px;height: auto;margin: 0 auto;text-align: center;padding: 10px;font-family: Verdena;">'.
            '<img src="'.$imgfooter.'" >'.
            '</div>'.
            '</body>';


        $phpmailer->IsHTML(true);
        $phpmailer->AddAddress(CONTACTUSFORMEMAIL);
        $phpmailer->From = CONTACTUSFORMEMAIL;
        $phpmailer->FromName ='blah';
        $phpmailer->WordWrap   = 50; // set word wrap to 50 characters
        $phpmailer->Subject    = $subject;
        $phpmailer->Body       = $message;
        $phpmailer->Send();



        $data['success'] = true;
        $data['message'] = 'Thank you for your application';
```

Comment: Do you want to attach a file located in another place than your server ?

Comment: add file path like /home/x/public_html/pdf/d.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is that the function [AddAttachment](http://www.tig12.net/downloads/apidocs/wp/wp-includes/class-phpmailer.php.source.html#line1124) uses the function [is_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php) and is file returns false when accessing URLs (this also applies to relative URLs), is_file() only accepts filepaths. So normally phpmailer should add an error to the error container.

Comment: That's correct. It does add an error to the error container, and return false for the function, or throw an exception if you enable exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Please try the following code

```
<?php
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->From = $email_from;
        $mail->SetFrom($email_from, $name_from);
        $mail->AddAddress($email_to, $name_to);
        $mail->AddReplyTo($email_from, $name_from);
        $mail->MsgHTML($message_goes_here);
        $mail->Subject = $your_subject;
        $mail->AddAttachment($file_name_goes_here);
        if($mail->Send()) {
        } else {
            echo "\r\nMail not sent. " .  $mail->ErrorInfo;
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The method [AddAttachment](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php#L2063) receives the path of the file.

If you see the source code, you will see that it uses fopen function to open the file, so, I think it doesn't work with links, you should download the file by yourself and pass the path to the function.

Comment: Would it therefore be possible to trim down my link to the file to be relative? e.g `/cv-folder/myfile.pdf` and instead use that? Why can't fopen open from full paths? The documentation doesn't seem to mention a problem with using full paths and provides some examples that use them: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Comment: `addAttachment` works perfectly well with both relative and absolute local file paths. It does *not* work with relative or absolute URLs because that's not what it's designed for - see my answer for how to do that. That `fopen` can do it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I know it might sound like a radical idea, but you could try [reading the docs](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html#method_addAttachment), or perhaps checking return values of functions, maybe even trying [an up to date version of PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), or basing your code on a recent example.

PHPMailer will only throw exceptions if you enable them at instantiation with `$mail = new PHPMailer(true);`, and as @TheGreenKey said, it will set an error notice and produce an error message if you enable debugging.

If you want to add URL contents as an an attachment, you can do this:

```
$mail->addStringAttachment(file_get_contents('http://mysite.co.uk/link/to/my/file.pdf'), 'cv.pdf');`
```

That's never going to be fast, reliable or efficient though.

Answer (score 0):

send any type of attachment using phpmailer.

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php';
if(isset($_POST['send']))
{
  $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name']; //attachment
  $file_tmp =$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
  
    $abc=microtime(); 
    $path="upload/$abc".$file_name;
    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$path); //moving attachment to upload folder
     
     
        $mail = new PHPMailer(true); 

        $mail->IsSMTP();                           
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = false;                 
        $mail->Port       = 25;                    
        $mail->Host       = "localhost"; 
        $mail->Username   = "webmail_username";   
        $mail->Password   = "webmail_password";            
    
        $mail->IsSendmail();  
    
        $mail->From       = "abc@your.com";
        $mail->FromName   = "your.com";
    
        $mail->AddAddress('receiver_emailid');
    
        $mail->Subject  = "Thank you for contacting US";
        $mail->WordWrap   = 80; 
    
        $body="Thank You For Contacting Us";

        $mail->MsgHTML($body);
        $mail->IsHTML(true); 
        
        $mail->AddAttachment($path,$file_name); //Attachment File
     
     
        if(!$mail->Send())
        {
               echo "Mail Not Sent";
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<script language="javascript">';
            echo 'alert("Thank You Contacting Us We Will Response You As Early Possible")';
            echo '</script>';
     
        }
```

}

for more details :- [click here](https://www.yourphpguru.com/send-email-with-attachment-using-phpmailer-on-godaddy/)